# knockout.js binds value only once

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of item. By clicking on a row I see edit form. Binding work just fine for first click. But whatever item I click second, third and etc time I see form filled with values from first click.

Item code initialization:

```
self.newManager = {
        UserId: ko.observable(),
        CustomerId: ko.observable(),
        UserName: ko.observable(),
        DisplayName: ko.observable(),
        Email: ko.observable(),
        IsActive: ko.observable(true),
        Password: ko.observable(),
        ConfirmPassword: ko.observable(),
        Roles: ko.observableArray()
    }
```

Get details code:

```
self.getManagerDetail = function (item) {
    self.newManager.UserId(item.UserId);
    self.newManager.UserName(item.UserName);
    self.newManager.DisplayName(item.DisplayName);
    self.newManager.Email(item.Email);
    self.newManager.IsActive(item.IsActive);
    self.newManager.CustomerId(item.CustomerId);
    self.newManager.Roles(item.Roles.$values);

    self.showManagerForm("editManagerForm");
}
```

Form HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="editManagerForm" style="display: block;" data-bind="submit: editManager">
<div class="form-group" data-bind="with: newManager">
<label class="control-label">Login</label>
<div data-bind="text: UserName"></div>
<label class="control-label" for="DisplayName1">Name</label>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" id="DisplayName1" type="text" data-bind="value: DisplayName" data-val="true">
</div>

<label class="control-label" for="Email1">Email</label>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" id="Email1" type="text" data-bind="value: Email" data-val="true">
</div>

<label class="control-label">Is active</label>
<div>
  <input class="form-control" id="IsActive" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsActive" data-val="true">
                        </div>
<label class="control-label">Roles</label>
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.roles">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="God" data-bind="checked: $parent.Roles, value: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: $data">God</span>
      </label>
  </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value="MarketingGuy" data-bind="checked: $parent.Roles, value: $data">
              <span data-bind="text: $data">MarketingGuy</span>
          </label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Accountant" data-bind="checked: $parent.Roles, value: $data">
                <span data-bind="text: $data">Accountant</span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Manager" data-bind="checked: $parent.Roles, value: $data">
                <span data-bind="text: $data">Manager</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default ajaxbutton" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

I checked self.getManagerDetail step by step in debugger. Values are set as I expect - self.newManager values are set as values from clicked item.

What could be a reason for this behavior?

Comment: can you please post your code/html from where you call `getManagerDetail`?

Comment: if possible, please post the viewmodel code so that we can take a look

Comment: Thanks for participation! I figured out the reason and posted it bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was caused by binding one object self.newManager to two form. I used it for edit and create forms. Once I change code to use one object for edit form and another for create form it starts to work just fine.

Hope it will be usefull.

And magic of getting things rigth in time you just explained thing worked again.

Comment: Good that you figured it out yourself